# What is $\mathbb Q +A=\{q+a : q\in \mathbb Q , a\in A\subset [0,1]\}$ $?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

What is $$\mathbb Q +A=\{q+a : q\in \mathbb Q , a\in A\}$$  where  $A$  is a  subset  of  the interval  $[0,1]$  with  ***non-empty  interior***  $?$

$A.\mathbb Q+A=\mathbb R$

$B.\mathbb Q+A $ can be a proper subset of $\mathbb R.$

$C.\mathbb Q+A$  need not be closed in $\mathbb R.$

$D.\mathbb Q+A$ need  not be open in $\mathbb R.$

This is  what  I  did  **:**

Since $A$ has non empty interior within $[0,1]$ there  is  some $(c,d)\subset A.$

So, $$(c,d)+\mathbb Q\subset A+\mathbb Q $$   Now,$$\mathbb Q+(c,d)=\cup_{q\in\mathbb Q} \{q+(c,d)\}$$
Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, we  see  the  above set contains $\mathbb Q^c$  as well.

For if $r\in \mathbb Q^c$ then we can form an interval of length $|d-c|$ that contains $r$ and whose starting point is a **rational** number say $q_1.$ Then $$r\in q_1+(c,d)$$ . So $$\mathbb Q+(c,d)=\mathbb R$$ hance proved $$\mathbb Q +A =\mathbb R.$$

Are my proof  and  answer  correct $?$

$P.S.:$  I saw this question has been asked before on this site but

$1)$ I did not understand their approach or the answer and

$2)$ I need  to  know  if  my  method  is  correct.

Thank  you  .

Comment: Yes, this approach is correct.

Comment: @ErickWong : So my answer is also  correct $?$

Comment: @GregMartin : Yes  the  question  happens  to  be  same  but as  a   post - mine is totally  different  than  the  one  you have  referred  to  and  kindly take another look at  my post, the  last  four  lines  - why do  you think I wrote them and you  marked it as duplicate  $? $

Comment: You have it alright but I dk what is meant by starting point. You can omit it and just say that for some $q_1\in Q$ we have  $q_1\in (r-d,r-c)$, hence $r\in q_1+(c,d)$.  Generalizing, note that the only property of $Q$ that is used is that it is dense.

Comment: @user254665 : thank you . By "starting point "  I  mean  "$c$"  if  the  interval  is  $(c,d)$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet sir how one can show that the set $\mathbb{Q}+A$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi .$\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q+A\iff  A\cap\Bbb Q\ne\emptyset.$