# How $\mathbb{Q}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}+A$

Tags: real-analysis

[What is $\mathbb Q +A=\{q+a : q\in \mathbb Q , a\in A\subset [0,1]\}$ $?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1580775/168676)

In the question given in above link, it is shown that “If $A$ is subset of $[0,1]$ with non empty interior then $\mathbb{Q}+A=\mathbb{R}$. But I am unable to get that, how $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}+A$ because for $\mathbb{Q}$ to be contained in $\mathbb{Q}+A=\{q+a:q\in\mathbb{Q},a\in A\}$ we must have $0\in A$.

Also please explains how $\mathbb{Q^c}$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}+A$(is there is any other approach)

Comment: Do you agree that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}+\{1\}=\{q+1:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: Because $A$ has nonempty interior, it contains some open interval, so it contains some rational. If $q$ is any rational, then $\mathbb{Q}+q=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You only need $A\cap \mathbb Q$ non-empty. However, it is not true if all elements of $A$ are irrational.

Comment: For all rationals $q$, there exists a rational $q' (= q-a)$ (where $a$ is arbitrary rational) such that $q = q' + a$.